# Changing sub domain name

Tags: sandbox, production, admin

I want to create tab for lightning components but I am unable to do so as I saw it is mandatory to change domain in order to create lightning component tabs. Currently my org is having various installed packages and process builders,flows. Changing domain name has some checks to be made before it like checking hard coded references in VF pages buttons,links which is a bit hectic.

Does anyone know any other way to create lightning component tab without changing domain ?

Comment: It looks like you might be confused. You have to activate "MyDomain", but there is no need to actually change it if it exists. You can specify a domain very easily, and it should not affect nor depend on any installed package.

Comment: Activating my domain is same as creating sub domain. My org has the original domain which was provided by salesforce. My question - is there a way to create lightning compoenent tab without activating mydomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question:

> is there a way to create lightning compoenent tab without activating mydomain?

You can create a lightning component without activating My Domain, however My Domain is a pre-requisite to use lightning components in your Org. You cannot use the components if you do not activate/deploy My Domain.

Below is the excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_reqs_my_domain.htm):

> You **must deploy My Domain** in your org if you want to use Lightning components in Lightning tabs, Lightning pages, as standalone apps, as actions and action overrides, as custom Lightning page templates, or elsewhere in your org.
>
> When My Domain isn’t deployed in your org, user interface controls related to Lightning components may be hidden or inactive. Lightning components added to pages, tabs, and so on, don’t run and may be omitted, or display a placeholder error message.